# Insert data in database (Mysql) from Lua table

Tags: mysql, insert, lua, bigdata, lua-table

I am trying to feed a table in a mysql database with something like 1 000 000 lines. 
I am using Lua and the function :

**conn:execute("INSERT INTO orders (dates, ordertype) VALUES ('"..tab[1][dateIndex]......**

for each line.
The problem is that it is very long and I really need more efficiency.
Do you have others solutions (maybe creating a .csv and loading it with mysql, maybe there is a function that can load a matrix in a database more efficiently,...). Using Lua is an obligation as I am using an existing project.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

First you can stop committing on each insert.

Also you can use prepared query. It provides by Lua-DBI and Lua-ODBC
I use ODBC.

```
local env = odbc.environment()
lcoal db = env:driverconnect{
  Driver = IS_WINDOWS and '{MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver}' or 'MySQL';
  db='test';
  uid='root';
};

cnn:set_autocommit(false)
local stmt = db:prepare("INSERT INTO orders (dates, ordertype) VALUES(?,?)")
for i, row in ipairs(tab) do
  stmt:bindstr(row[dateIndex])
  ...
  stmt:execute()
  if i % 1000 == 0 then
    cnn:commit()
  end
end
```

Also ODBC provide variables. May be the could be faster because they do not call SQLBindParam each time.

```
   -- create stmt as preview
   ...
   local dateValue = odbc.date():bind_param(stmt, 1)
   local orderValue = odbc.ulong():bind_param(stmt, 2) 

    for i, row in ipairs(tab) do
      dateValue:set(row[1]) -- data is yyyy-mm-dd e.g. 2014-10-14
      orderValue:set(row[2])
      stmt:execute()
      ...
      -- same as preview
```